# Get Row Data on click of row

Tags: jquery, fuelux

I have used a fuelux library to make a table and below is the code I have for the columns

```
items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = {
    id : i,
    action :'<a href="" onclick="editRow()" >Edit</a>|<a href="" onclick="deleteRow()" >Delete</a>' , 
    name : data[i].Name,
    startRange : data[i].StartRange__c,
    endRange : data[i].EndRange__c,
    oldRiskGrade : data[i].OldRiskGrade__c,
    reportingRiskGrade : data[i].ReportingRiskGrade__c,
    approvalType : data[i].ApprovalType__c,
    displayValueRiskGrade : data[i].RiskGradeDisplayValue__c
  }
  items.push(item);
}
```

now when I click on the edit or delete link I want to get the data for the row clicked and also prevent it to refresh the whole page. Somehow fuelux does not have a proper documentation to get the row data. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the id parameter in editrow() and deleterow() to identify the row identity:

```
   items = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var item = {
              id: i,
              action: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="editRow(' + i + ')" >Edit</a>|<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteRow(' + i + ')" >Delete</a>',
              name: data[i].Name,
              startRange: data[i].StartRange__c,
              endRange: data[i].EndRange__c,
              oldRiskGrade: data[i].OldRiskGrade__c,
              reportingRiskGrade: data[i].ReportingRiskGrade__c,
              approvalType: data[i].ApprovalType__c,
              displayValueRiskGrade: data[i].RiskGradeDisplayValue__c
          }
          items.push(item);
      }
```

On click get the parameter from them and fetch the relevant data from the Item[]

Comment: I got the data by looping through the item array but still it refreshes the whole page on click of delete or edit. How can i prevent the page refresh?

Comment: Can you pls provide the code of editRow() or Delete()

Comment: function deleteRow(id){
for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
console.log();
if(i == id){
deleteData(items[i].name);
break;
}
}
}

Comment: In attribute href use `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped.